# Parse query returning nil?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have the following code, which is expected to perform a query in the User table to find the row which has an email equal to "test@live.com" and signedUpWith to "facebook" as shown below:

```
var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")

    userQuery.whereKey("email", equalTo: "test@live.com")
    userQuery.whereKey("signedUpWith", equalTo: "facebook")


    var userResults: [PFObject]? = nil

    do {
        userResults = try userQuery.findObjects()
    } catch  {

    }
```

However for some reason, when printing the userResults.count gives 0 and the userResults object is nil.

BTW: these values EXIST in my table row

Does anyone understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `PFQuery(className: "_User")` since it's a designated Parse class.

More appropriately, you should be using `var userQuery = PFUser.query`